# Migrating raid array between different controllers

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid

Recently my motherboard unexpectedly gave out, there are two disks attached in RAID 0. The controller in question for this motherboard is a ICH9R. Due to the sparse availability of hardware I am unable to obtain a replica or one having the same controller. On advice of peers I was going to attempt to recover the data on a board with a new(er) controller - in keeping in thought backwards compatiblity.

However as it turns out the new system is malfunctioning and thus I can't be used to recover the volume. The only other system at my disposal is ICH7-based. The intel site mentions raid volumes are transferable amongst different i/o controllers as long as it supports the designated raid configuration.  But their article is particularly focused on upgrading chipsets and this would be a downgrade(?). So I am a bit skeptical to naively try it out. In what degree is this possible, safe? What sort of information should i determine/compare to asses this for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why not simply move your disks to a new system and then restore the data from a backup? (Note the RAID mantra: "RAID is not a replacement for backup. RAID is not a replacement for backup.  RAID is not a replacement for backup. " ...)

Or, possibly more helpful: Boot from a Linux liveCD and use the `dm` driver to read the disks. Then, once you got access to the data copy it to the network, reformat the disks and copy the data back.

---

I say the 'reformat the disks' because you want to have a safe way of reading this should this happen again. That means either software RAID (not hardware bound. Both windows, Linux, BSD's etc etc support this), or hardware RAID with a spare compatible HW RAID card, or Fake RAID (which was what you used) with a compatible spare motherboard.

Comment: Simply put, a vast amount of data, is already out of sync with their  respective backups (such as dangling changesets in mecurial repositories) or have not be done. So I prefer restoring the origional - if the disks itself are not affected this seems more than a reasonable decision.

I will have to check the linux solution out, admitedly, i'm not linux savy. So I have a bit reading to do what it extactly does etc.

Comment: `md` is the normal Linux software RAID. `dm` is the Intel RAID software RAID under Linux. Fot the rest: there are many webpages which probably describe it in quite some detail than I can.